# Get 'Location Name' from Facebook Messenger Pinned Map - Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to get all location details from pinned map on facebook messenger. Is there a way one can retrieve the **Name** of location from the pinned map using Bot Frame work. So far I am able to get co-ordinates using code below:

`double longitude = data.message.attachments[0].payload.coordinates["long"];
double latitude = data.message.attachments[0].payload.coordinates["lat"];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a geocoding API with these coordinates. There are several possibilites: Google Maps, Bing Maps, Here, etc.

Comment: @NicolasR do you have any implementation of geocoding for Google Maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse